# react-navigation native-stack Stack Navigator Screen keep blank

Tags: react-native, navigation

I was following the React navigation to create the pages, however, I only get the blank page when I build the application.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

React navigation version

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

Here is my full code on App.js
On this page, I created 3 function: `HomeSc`, `HomeScCheck`, `DetailSc`.
Only the `HomeScCheck` can show on the screen.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text , SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';


function HomeScCheck() {
  return (
    <View><Text style={{color:"red"}}>Home Screen Check</Text></View>
  );
}

function HomeSc() {
  return (
    <View><Text>Home Screen</Text></View>
  );
}

function DetailSc() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={{color: '#333', fontSize:30}}>Detail Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeSc} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailSc}   options={{ title: 'Overview' }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      <HomeScCheck/>  
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you were saying that you want to see the `HomeScCheck` screen as the first screen, you should see when the app is run.

So, to do that your code should look as the following code.

```js
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScCheck() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Home Screen Check</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function HomeSc() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailSc() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text style={{ color: '#333', fontSize: 30 }}>Detail Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home Check" component={HomeScCheck} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeSc} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Detail"
          component={DetailSc}
          options={{ title: 'Overview' }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So, What I have done is that I have removed the `<safeareaview>` and `<HomeScCheck>` and I have created another `<Stack.Screen>` above the home `<Stack.Screen>`. Though this tells that the first `<Stack.Screen>` will be the first screen of the **stack navigator**.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove safeAreaView and statusbar from the App.js file
only put Navigation inside the return

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'** instead of **import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';**